# Typescript multiple type definition

Tags: typescript

I have defined the `interface` in a `d.ts` file:

```
declare module myModule
{
    interface IQedModel {
        field: string | string[];
        operator: string;

    }
}
```

In an anuglar controller I have implemented it:

```
vm.filters = <myModule.IQedModel>{
    operator: 'and',
    field: []
};

function populateFields() {
    vm.filters.field = [];

    angular.forEach(addedFilters, item => {
        vm.filters.field.push(item.data); //<-- THIS LINE SHOWS ERRORS
    });
}
```

The error is:

> Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'

What is the issue here?

Comment: The compiler cannot infer the type.You should cast to the array: `(vm.filters.field as string[]).push(...)`

Comment: @BGR is that not what the line at the top of the function does?

Comment: Obvioussly the compiler is falling back to the type definition: if you remove the cast to `<myModule.IQedModel>` on the assignment to `vm.filters` the compiler will infer the array and will not complain. (the assignment within the `populateFields` function is unnecessary)

Comment: Okay cool, I was migrating a JS file to TS so that's why it is there, I guess I'm going to run into a lot of relics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on BGR comments I need to cast to an array first:

```
(<string[]>vm.filters.field).push(item.data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics:

```
declare module myModule
{
    interface IQedModel<T> {
        field: T;
        operator: string;

    }
}

var filters = <myModule.IQedModel<Array<string>>>{
    operator: 'and',
    field: []
};

var filters2 = <myModule.IQedModel<string>>{
    operator: 'and',
    field: ""
};

filters.field.push(""); // works
// filters.field = "" // String not assignable to string[]


filters2.field = ""; // works
// filters2.field.push(""); // push does not exist on type string
```

Or:

```
declare module myModule
{
    interface IQedModel<T> {
        field: T;
        operator: string;

    }

    interface ISingleFieldQedModel extends IQedModel<string> {}
    interface IMultiFieldQedModel extends IQedModel<string[]> {}
}

var filters = <myModule.IMultiFieldQedModel>{
    operator: 'and',
    field: []
};

filters.field.push("");
// filters.field = "" // String not assignable to string[]


var filters2 = <myModule.ISingleFieldQedModel>{
    operator: 'and',
    field: ""
};

filters2.field = "";
// filters2.field.push(""); // push does not exist on type string
```

You can also use Type Guards, take a look to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx) but there are some [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1719) at the moment.

Comment: I like that, neat stuff!